# Inconsistent scoring in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to enable full text search across the tags (keyword phrases) I have created that can be assigned to documents in my index (named "Delta").

My results are (1) not what I would expect and (2) not consistent if I re-run the same code repeatedly.

Below is some code. I have simplified the mappings and documents to make the code clearer and to make sure the problem wasn't in some other part of the documents or mappings. I am running all of this using the Kibana Dev Tools Console.

```
PUT /mdelta 
{
  "mappings":{
    "tags":{
      "properties":{
        "synonyms":{ 
          "type":"text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Iron"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Fe"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Iron Deficiency"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Serum Iron"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Iron Sulfate"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "mdelta", "_type" : "tags" }}
{"synonyms":"Iron Deficiency Anemia"}

GET mdelta/tags/_search
{
    "explain":false,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "synonyms" : "iron"
        }
    }
}
```

Based on my understanding of the scoring algorithm, I would expect the document `{"synonyms":"Iron"}` to be returned first (top score). This is not the case. Results ...

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0.5377023,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj9",
        "_score": 0.5377023,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Sulfate"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj5",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj8",
        "_score": 0.25811607,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Serum Iron"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj7",
        "_score": 0.1805489,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj-",
        "_score": 0.14638957,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency Anemia"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I repeated the query with explain set to true.

```
{
  "took": 38,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0.5377023,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[mdelta][4]",
        "_node": "McQ619KqR0akS1mHvTXjDw",
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj9",
        "_score": 0.5377023,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Sulfate"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.5377023,
          "description": "weight(synonyms:iron in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.5377023,
              "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.6931472,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "docFreq",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "docCount",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.7757405,
                  "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "parameter k1",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "parameter b",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.5,
                      "description": "avgFieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.56,
                      "description": "fieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[mdelta][2]",
        "_node": "McQ619KqR0akS1mHvTXjDw",
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj5",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.2876821,
          "description": "weight(synonyms:iron in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.2876821,
              "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.2876821,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "docFreq",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "docCount",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "parameter k1",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "parameter b",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "avgFieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "fieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[mdelta][3]",
        "_node": "McQ619KqR0akS1mHvTXjDw",
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj8",
        "_score": 0.25811607,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Serum Iron"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.25811607,
          "description": "weight(synonyms:iron in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.25811607,
              "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.2876821,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "docFreq",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "docCount",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.89722675,
                  "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "parameter k1",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "parameter b",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "avgFieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.56,
                      "description": "fieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[mdelta][1]",
        "_node": "McQ619KqR0akS1mHvTXjDw",
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj7",
        "_score": 0.1805489,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.1805489,
          "description": "weight(synonyms:iron in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.1805489,
              "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.18232156,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "docFreq",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "docCount",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.9902773,
                  "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "parameter k1",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "parameter b",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.5,
                      "description": "avgFieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.56,
                      "description": "fieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[mdelta][1]",
        "_node": "McQ619KqR0akS1mHvTXjDw",
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "AWA8jRR9YXA6OBvYOfj-",
        "_score": 0.14638957,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency Anemia"
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.14638956,
          "description": "weight(synonyms:iron in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.14638956,
              "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.18232156,
                  "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "docFreq",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "docCount",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.8029196,
                  "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "parameter k1",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "parameter b",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.5,
                      "description": "avgFieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 4,
                      "description": "fieldLength",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you look at the first hit ("Iron Sulfate"), it appears that the docFreq is 1 and the docCount is 2. This is incorrect.

In addition, if I run `delete /mdelta` and then re-run my code, I can get a different order of the results for example ...

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "Qd0JQWABt4cFDxBHv7Fe",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Serum Iron"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "Pt0JQWABt4cFDxBHv7Fe",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "QN0JQWABt4cFDxBHv7Fe",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "Qt0JQWABt4cFDxBHv7Fe",
        "_score": 0.19856805,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Sulfate"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mdelta",
        "_type": "tags",
        "_id": "Q90JQWABt4cFDxBHv7Fe",
        "_score": 0.16853254,
        "_source": {
          "synonyms": "Iron Deficiency Anemia"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What analyzer are you using on the synonym field?

Comment: Standard analyzer since I don't specify anything. From elastic 6.0 documentation `At index time, if no analyzer has been specified, it looks for an analyzer in the index settings called default. Failing that, it defaults to using the standard analyzer.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for not getting consistent results on reindexing the data is that the term-frequencies are calculated per shard. On reindexing, the shard allocation differs from the previous index since you don't specify any routing.

The problem:

> not getting what [you] expect

from elastic is perhaps because of the small number of documents in your index. Try running the query with parameter `search_type` like so: `GET mdelta/tags/_search?search_type= dfs_query_then_fetch`.
This ensures that it calculates index level frequencies first. 
You can use this in development, but i don't think it's advisable in production. If you have enough data, the frequencies should be more or less the same across shards.

see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html

Comment: Fantastic. Nice clear exaplanation. Thanks. Just to make sure I was clear on this for myself, I also tested this forcing a single shard which also corrected my issue. Not a long term solution but now I understand more clearly.

Comment: glad to help :)